# SVG <text> with relative coordinates to each other

Tags: html, svg

I got the following svg:

```html
<svg>
    <text x="10" y="15">
        <tspan dx="0">Text 1</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 2</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 3</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 4</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="30" y="30">
        <tspan dx="0">Text 5</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 6</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 7</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 8</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="50" y="45">
        <tspan dx="0">Text 1</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 2</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 3</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 4</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="10" y="60">
        <tspan dx="0">Text 5</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 6</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 7</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 8</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

This is just an example and it will become extremely complex. As you can see, I have to change the x and y value every single time for a new line to get it positioned properly.

Is it possible to make these values relative? The grid will always look the same, if they are relative I can set them once or put them into a var and copy paste everything.

For example something like this (I know it's not working / looking the same, just to demonstrate my idea)

```html
<svg>
    <text dx="15" dy="20">
        <tspan dx="15">Text 1</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 2</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 3</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 4</tspan>
    </text>
    <text dx="15" dy="20">
        <tspan dx="15">Text 5</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 6</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 7</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 8</tspan>
    </text>
    <text dx="15" dy="20">
        <tspan dx="15">Text 1</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 2</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 3</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 4</tspan>
    </text>
    <text dx="15" dy="20">
        <tspan dx="15">Text 5</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 6</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 7</tspan>
        <tspan dx="15">Text 8</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you're working with large amounts of text you'd be better off in the world of HTML rather than SVG.

Comment: Thats true, but I don't want it to look like keyword stuffing for google, because there will be multiple, repeating short words

Comment: You can't have identical relative offsets on every line if the offset resets occasionally (like it does between the third and fourth line in your example).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau well, ok. But that doesn't matter. It will be put inside a wrapper and I can just push it more to the left with the same effect. But how would you do the relative y offset?

Comment: Well you can use `dy="15"` for a new line, as long as it's all inside the same `<text>` element.  But you are always going to need to adjust the start X position with either an `x` or `dx` (or a `transform`)